# failing to insert dynamic form fields in php its saying array array in the data base

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, pdo

1. When i submit the form its sayings submitted but no data in the database its just saying array array
   2.and its not sure any error
   3.from the form html to php if i print_r() its printing all the data from the form but after inserting just one is inserted and it is as i described above **array array array** thank you in advance am new to php OOP PDO

here is my code for php and the html form

```
  public function addinvoice($data){
    //Insert Query
    for($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++){
    $this->db->query('INSERT INTO tbl_invoice (users_id,customer_id,companies_id,productname,quantity,price,sub_total,total_tax,total,last_activity)
                            values (:users_id,:customer_id,:companies_id,:productname,:quantity,:price,:sub_total,:total_tax,:total,:last_activity)');
    //Bind Values
    $this->db->bind(':users_id', $data['users_id'][$i]);
    $this->db->bind(':customer_id', $data['customer_id'][$i]);
    $this->db->bind(':companies_id', $data['companies_id'][$i]);
    $this->db->bind(':productname', $data['productname'][$i]);
    $this->db->bind(':quantity', $data['quantity'][$i]);
    $this->db->bind(':price', $data['price'][$i]);
    $this->db->bind(':sub_total', $data['sub_total'][$i]);
    $this->db->bind(':total_tax', $data['total_tax'][$i]);
    $this->db->bind(':total', $data['total'][$i]);
    $this->db->bind(':last_activity', $data['last_activity'][$i]);

    if($this->db->execute()){
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
    //echo $this->db->lastInsertid
  }
```

second

```
//Create Invoice Object
$invoice = new Invoice;
//Create validator Object
$validate = new Validator;

if (isset($_POST['add_invoice'])) {
    //Creatr Data array
    $data = array();
    $data['productname'] = $_POST['productname'];
    $data['quantity'] = $_POST['quantity'];
    $data['price'] = $_POST['price'];
    $data['amount'] = $_POST['amount'];
    $data['sub_total'] = $_POST['sub_total'];
    $data['total_tax'] = $_POST['total_tax'];
    $data['total'] = $_POST['total'];
    $data['companies_id'] = $_POST['companies_id'];
    $data['customer_id'] = $_POST['customer_id'];
    $data['users_id'] = getUser()['users_id'];
    $data['last_activity'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    //echo your results



$field_array = array('productname','quantity', 'price');
if ($validate->isRequired($field_array)) {
 //register  User
    if ($invoice->addinvoice($data)){

        redirect('addinvo.php', 'You are registered and can now log in', 'success');
    } else {
        redirect('addinvo.php', 'Something went wrong with registration', 'error');
    }
} else {
    redirect('addinvo.php',  'All fields are required',  'error');
}


}
```

and my html form

```
    <form role="form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="addinvo.php"  class="field">

            <?php include 'invoiceheader.php' ?>
           <!--Search bar and filter ends -->
            Bill to:
            <?php if(!empty ($clients)) : ?>
            <div class="form-right">
                <input type="hidden" name="customer_id" value="<?php echo $clients->c_id; ?>">
                <textarea name="address" id="" cols="40" rows="2" readonly ><?php echo $clients->address; ?> </textarea>
            </div>
            <?php else : ?>
                <br>
                <br>
                <span class="error">No client selected</span>
          <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
        <!-- User data starts -->
    <div id="form-btn">
            <button  id="btn" type="button" onclick="addRows()" >&plus; Add</button>
            <button  id="btn" type="button" onclick="deleteRows()">&minus; remove</button>
        </div>
        <table  id="emptbl">
            <tr>
                <th>s/n</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Unit Price</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
            </tr>
            <tbody class="detail">
            <tr>
                <div class="inputfield">
                    <td class="no">1</td>
                    <td ><textarea name="productname[]" class="productname" id="" cols="35" rows="2" ></textarea></td>
                    <td ><input id="quantit"  name="quantity[]" class="quantity" type="number"  onchange="Calc(this);"></td>
                    <td ><input id="prices"  name="price[]" class="price" type="number" onchange="Calc(this);"></td>
                    <td ><input  name="amount[]" class="amount" type="text"  ></td>
                </div>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                    <th  id="col0"></th>
                    <th  id="col1"></th>
                    <th  id="col2"></th>
                    <th  id="col3">Total</th>
                    <th><input type="number"  id="finalTotal" name="total"  readonly></th>
            </tfoot>
            <tfoot>
                    <th  id="col0"></th>
                    <th  id="col1"></th>
                    <th  id="col2"></th>
                    <th  id="col3">Sub Total</th>
                    <th><input  type="number" id="sub_total"  name="sub_total"  readonly></th>
            </tfoot>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th  id="col0"></th>
                    <th  id="col1"></th>
                    <th  id="col2"></th>
                    <th  id="col3">Vat </th>
                    <th><input id="total_tax" type="number" name="total_tax" value="" ></th>

                </tr>
            </tfoot>

        </table>
        <div id="form-btn">
            <button  id="btn" type="submit" name="add_invoice">Save</button>
            <!--<button type="button" id="doPrint">&plus;Print</button>-->
        </div>
    </form>
```

I searched on google i couldn't see any result for my specific issue
have been trying its now a week
I tried to use for and foreach it failed not sure what am doing wrong

Comment: *its just saying array array*: **what's** just saying "array array"? What happens if you log or write `count(d$ata)` in your php page? What do you see if you log or write `$data['users_id'][$i]` within your loop in your php page?

Comment: Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type int

Comment: Where exactly is that logging from? What is `$i` at that point? What does the `$data['users_id']` look like at that point?

Comment: from Functions .$i is an int .At that point the data is an Int it is a hidden parameter passed through input field

Comment: Yes, it's an index in the loop, but what is its *value* when you are getting "Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type int"?

Comment: its not showing but if i remove $I from there, its showing the the actual user_id and insert the value not array array buy just a single value excluding other dynamic data

Comment: So users_id doesn't seem to be in your form; it does seem to be assigned another way. Is that value actually an array? Can you log `$data['users_id']` and `$i` in your loop so you can see their values?

Comment: if i remove $i the value of users_id is shown based on user_id if its one it will show 1 if i remove the $i and insert the data in the database but its not solving my problem cause what i want is to insert dynamic input fields in the database

Comment: Do you have multiple `users_id`s? If you remove the `$i` for users_id, do the remaining fields insert correctly?

Comment: I have a primary key which is a foreign key in the other table passed through a form input field a single user can be selected using the fk then  as have tested again its found that $i is equal to zero [0] when you print_r. If i remove $i only a single row is inserted apart from the other row correctly except i want to submit all the rows

Comment: You have a `return` statement within your loop, so it runs the first iteration and returns. Hence no subsequent iterations.

Comment: so i end the loop before return

Comment: Anyone who can  help me here please have tried a lot its still not working have tried to use implode it inserting all the values in one row

Comment: _"have tried to use implode it inserting all the values in one row"_ - if you want to create individual records, then you will have to loop over your data, instead of imploding it.

Comment: What else are you stuck on? You have to move your return statement outside of the loop.

Comment: tried that it is inserting many totals, vats and subtotals in the database if  i remove it out side the loop not sure the best way to do it now have tried many things so far